# What would be the way to replace a observable array in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

Instead of just assigning newGroups. How would it be done with Vue.$set to keep the observable array ?

```
   this.groups = newGroups;
```

Comment: What's the issue? Either assigning a new array or using $set will preserve reactivity.

Comment: @Bert Would this.$set(this.groups, newGroups) keep the observable array ?

Comment: I don't think this is a case where you need $set. In the code you present, `this.groups` will have the `newGroups` value and it will be reactive.

Answer (score 0):

Use [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice). This works nicely with the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)

```
this.groups.splice(0, this.groups.length, ...newGroups);
```